Is there a point to splitting a blog post into multiple parts?
I write blogposts on Computer Science (not specifically about programming though). Usually my posts are 1500 to 2500 words long. The one I am currently writing will probably end up being 7,000 words or longer.
I was wondering about the point splitting the topic into multiple blog posts "My Topic - Part 1", "My Topic - Part 2" etc but publishing all the parts at the same time.
Several guidelines about blogs in general advise keeping a post to 2000 odd words - but their reasons seem to be stuff like search engine optimisation, keeping the reader interested etc.
SEO is not the most important thing to me. I care about it but not so much that it will be the only thing I am going to base the decision on.
What I am writing is more like an in-depth guide to a particular topic. I checked other blog posts on the same topic. I found one which was split into 5 separate blog posts each linked forward & backwards. Another person wrote it like a book & had 5-6 chapters (each chapter on a different page) and published the whole thing as a webbook like guide to the topic.
I am wondering if there is a point to splitting into separate pages. The only reason would be because reader may not finishing the whole thing in one sitting so it would be easier for him to come back to the right part - i.e. he will remember I have finished Part 2 last time, so I need to start Part 3 now.
I am thinking of splitting it but keeping it all on the same page and having a table of contents - which shows 5 parts with each part having a descriptive title & each part being a clickable link - so the reader can jump from the TOC to the right part.
Are there any guidelines which specifically deal with this for technical blog posts?

I worry that your eventual question - "What do people think? Does anyone have any different perspective or other ideas?" - is very opinion-based. Could you reword this to be more objective?

Is it better now @F1Krazy?

That's much better. Welcome to Writing.SE!

Related: How long is too long for a blog post?

@Laurel - I did search & read that before posting this. His question is specific to where he is writing - some particular blog - "Universe Factory" - which usually has short posts. So he is asking if a long post will work in a place which usually has short posts - my question isn't like that

I'm in the "split long articles and use a TOC" camp.  I do it quite a bit on my blog - I've got 17 such TOCs, each with anywhere from three to nearly 20 parts.
The question isn't really whether to split things or not.  The question is really "what is your goal?"
If you've got something to say that is short and to the point about a subject, then a single post may be all you need.  If you've got a lot to say with a lot of details to go with it then you really need to consider splitting things up.
Can you express your ideas with adequate detail in a couple of thousand words?  If you can, then there's no need for more parts.  If you can't get all the things you need to include squeezed into that limit, then you need multiple parts.
The question mentions a 7000 word blog post.  I think I'd split that into two, maybe three posts with a TOC - and probably expand it to five or six blog posts.  The additional posts are not padding.  The idea is that since you are already going into some detail, you might as well go "whole hog" and do a good job on the details.
I tend to use a structure sort of like this:

TOC
Introduction (including the conclusion that the series is going to make.)
Sub Topic 1
Sub Topic 2
Sub Topic 3
Sub Topic ...
Summary (including the conclusion that the series was intended to make.)
Addons after the series conclusion in response to reader comments.

Along with that, I recommend that you do not write such a series then post it all at once.
"Blog" comes from "weblog."  It is a log of your ongoing experiences - a diary if you will.
If you collect stuff up and post it all in a big blob, you are breaking that expectation of an ongoing story.  Depending on how large the subject is, it may take you weeks or months to get all the parts finished.  In that time, you may not be able to make other posts - that leaves your readers hanging.
Work at it steadily and post parts as you complete them.  That means you have to have an outline of the project before you start - it also means that you may have to back track and provide a correction to some earlier part in a later post if you make a mistake.  That's fine.  Edit the earlier (incorrect part) with a reference to the later part that corrects the inaccuracy.  The blog reflects your learning path, and you will ocassionally get things wrong.
You are writing a blog, not a text book.

Keep it as accurate as you can.
Keep it up to date
Update as you complete each part.
Insert additions in old posts to link to corrections in newer posts.


 In that time, you may not be able to make other posts - that leaves your readers hanging. - I don't have any regular readers who wait for my posts. I usually post not more than 7 to 10 posts a year. I get my readers usually because someone has linked my post in their post as a reference

In my opinion, if the content of your post is about the same topic, it is better not to split the content for a better experience of the readers, but if by dividing the content, each post still provides its own content to the reader, it is better to split it for ease of reading.
